# notifications for new comments on my web site (using facebook social plugin)

Tags: facebook, notifications

i added the fb:comments social plugin to my website. now i want to receive notifications when someone add a new comment.

i tried with adding `send_notification_uid="<myusername>"` in the `<fb:comments>` tag but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

See this page :
http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/02/02/fbcomments-tag-no-longer-notifying-users/

It look like FB doesn't support notification anymore on that social plugin.